# Suma de N primeros pares y producto de N primeros impares

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio de java, estoy empezando con el lenguaje:

Hacer un programa que calcule y muestre la suma de los N primeros números pares y el producto de los N primeros números impares simultáneamente, siendo N un número que se introduce por teclado.

Como se podría hacer este ejercicio?

He llegado hasta aquí, pero cuando le doy me salen los resultados de las multiplicaciones en 0

```
int contador = 0;
int contador1 = 0; 
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
for (i=0; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        contador +=i;
        System.out.println(contador);
    }
}   System.out.println("\n");
for (j=1; j <= num; j++) {
    if (j % 2 !=0) {
        contador1 *=j;
        System.out.println((double)contador1);
    }
}
```

Comment: necesitamos codigo y decirnos donde tienes el problema o que no entiendes

Comment: Hazlo con un for, inicializas una variable int i en 2 y pones i++,i++ y con un contador para que valla sumando esos pares, igual para los impares, inicializas en 1 y vas sumando de a 2 para que solo tome impares, 1 +2 = 3 + 2 = 5 y asi.

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo es utilizar el operador % (sirve para obtener el resto de una división entera). Haces un for recorriendo todos los números y dentro un if. Si i%2==0 entonces es par, en caso contrario es impar.

Comment: El problema es que quiero multiplicar los impares y a la hora de poner multiplicación en los impares me da el resultado 0 en todos

Comment: Hey Vlad Tepes, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: @VladT has un `if((i%2)==0){sumas}else{multiplicas}`

Comment: for (i=0; i <= num; i+=2) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
   contador +=i;
   System.out.println(contador);
  } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
   contador1 *=i;
   System.out.println(contador1);
  }                              He hecho esto y no me sale

Comment: @VladT Vlad Tepes, agrega ese código a tu pregunta para que la comunidad vea lo que realizaste y a partir de ello responder.

Comment: @VladT Cambia el for por for (i=0; i <= num; i++)

Comment: @VladT No es necesario que agregues ese `Else-if`, si sabes que un numero no entra por **par**, es por que es **impar**, de resto esta bien.

Comment: Otra cosa que había pensado era esto:  int contador = 0;
 int contador1 = 0; 
 int i = 0;
 int j = 1;
 for (i=0; i <= num; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
   contador +=i;
   System.out.println(contador);
  }
 } System.out.println("\n");
 for (j=1; j <= num; j++) {
  if (j % 2 !=0) {
   contador1 *=j;
   System.out.println((double)contador1);
  }
 }  Pero sigue sin salir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira he realizado un ejercicio con lo que pides, es fácil de comprender pero cualquier duda pregunta, lo único que debes hacer como te dicen en los comentarios es preguntar si `(variable %2 == 0)` para saber si es par, con un else ya validas que son impares y haces el producto de los impares

Código:

```
public class Main 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner tecla = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numero ,inicial = 1 ,suma = 0,producto = 1;

        System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
        numero = tecla.nextInt();

        while(inicial < numero)
        {
            if(inicial%2==0)
            {
                suma = suma + inicial;
            }
            else
            {
                producto = producto * inicial;
            }
            inicial++;
        }

        System.out.println("\n La suma de los numero pares es: "+suma);
        System.out.println("\n El producto de los numeros impares es: "+producto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya tengo la duda resuelta

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que inicializas la variable contador1 a 0, por tanto todas las multiplicaciones dan como resultado 0.

```
int contador = 0;
int contador1 = 1;  //inicializamos contador1 a 1 
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
for (i=0; i <= num; i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
       contador +=i;
       System.out.println(contador);
}
}     System.out.println("\n");
for (j=1; j <= num; j++) {
    if (j % 2 !=0) {
        contador1 *=j;
        System.out.println((double)contador1);
    }
}
```

Además, deberías tener en cuenta que no necesitas tener dos for, ya que solo necesitas uno para recorrer todos los números (si un número no es par, entonces será impar).

Comment: Exacto, ahí el problema.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con el siguiente código, no lo he probado pero iría básicamente así:

```
int num = 10;
int cont1=0;
int cont2=1:

for(i=0;i<num;i++){ 
if ((i % 2) == 0){ 
cont1 = cont1 + i; 
System.out.println(contador); 
}else{ 
cont2 = cont2 * i; 
System.out.println(contador1); 
}
```

Comment: No funciona, sigue sin salir la multiplicación